# Is there an integrable function that dominates $f_n(x)=\frac{\chi_{[0,n]}(x)}{n \ln (n)}$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Is there an integrable function (with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$) that dominates $\displaystyle f_n(x)=\frac{\chi_{[0,n]}(x)}{n \ln (n)}$ for all $n \geq 2$? How can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g$ dominates this sequence then $\int_0^{\infty} g(x)dx\geq \sum_n \int_n^{n+1} g(x)dx \geq 
\sum_n \frac 1 {(n+1) \ln (n+1)}=\infty$. Hence no such dominating function exists.

Comment: The fact that $\sum \frac  1{n \ln n} =\infty$ can be proved using the integral test and making the substitution $y=\ln x$. I will be happy to provide a more detailed proof if asked for.

Comment: Can this also be seen by showing that the dominated convergence theorem doesn't hold? Like in this question?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792811/lebesgue-integral-no-dominating-integrable-function-of-f-n

Comment: In this case the limit of the integral and the integral of the limit are both $0$. So the conclusion of DCT holds even though there is no dominating integrable function. @Twink

Comment: Kavi Rama Mirthy: Thanks. I guess I can do the same with the sequence $f_n=\frac{\chi_{[0.n]}(x)}{n^p}$ for $0<p<\infty$. For $p <1$, there isn't a dominating function, is that right?

Comment: @Twink Yes, you are right.